# Decrease time complexity in activity

Tags: android, algorithm, performance, data-structures, time-complexity

I have a timeline activity that will display users status using recyclerview. I'm using firebase server and rxjava to fetch data from database. Using Array List in my timeline adapter, i'm storing all the status objects. I am performing `Insertions, Deletion and Updation` operations in my timeline activity based on status uid. As i'm using Array List, the time complexity for insertion is O(1) but for deletion and updation the time complexity will be O(n). If there are thousands of records, it will take time to perform `Deletion and Updation` operation. In order to improve my time complexity, I used Hashmap that will store status uid and index. Like in below code

```
fun addStatus(status : Status?){
  statusList.add(status)
  statusMap.put("uid",status?.uid)
  statusMap.put("index",statusList?.indexOf(status)?.toString)
  notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Using HashMap, time complexity in worst case improves but it also gives me some issues when trying to delete status from statusList. When i perform delete operation in my arrayList, the index of remaining objects next to the object that is deleted will changed. It also forced me to update my HashMap indexing of remaining objects. In worst case if there are millions of records, HashMap will perform `Update` operation in O(1) but `Delete` operation will take O(k) time complexity.
How can i improve my code to perform all three operations in O(1) time else suggest me any better data structure that gonna work best in my case.Thanks

Comment: HashMap has a time complexity of O(1) for containsKey, put *and* remove. For remove it's amortized O(1) meaning that it's O(1) if there aren't a lot of collisions in your hashcode() function. But as you use a primitive number as key there shouldn't be any collisions.

Comment: yes time complexity will be O(1) for constant keys.  I am facing the problem in Array List in removing objects as it also force me to update my indexing in Hash Map every time when i remove objects from Array List. I need a solution where i don't have to update my Hash Map Else if you know any better data structure that can give O(1) time complexity for three operations then suggest me that also.

Comment: Well, not if the order matters (You could use HashSet otherwise). If you really want the performance benefit you'll have to stick with this UID-mapping attempt. What you can try is dropping the ArrayList entirely and instead using a SparseIntArray to map List position -> UID. But as you'll have to maintain this mapping as well I'm not sure there would be a real benefit. (Sidenode: I use this handy sheet for the complexity values: https://gist.github.com/psayre23/c30a821239f4818b0709)

Comment: Well , I haven't tried SparseIntArray. can you please share any code of SparseIntArray.

Comment: When removing object from Array List, what if i store a status object whose values are set to default and put a check in onBindHolder() and check whether the object values are not set to default. If values are not default then condition is true and it may process further. This won't force to update indexing in HashMap.